# JPA - ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

Tags: java, jpa, oracle11g

I am using Spring JPA to retrieve data from Oracle DB.I am passing string parameters

Code:

```
@Repository
public interface TbBamiTemplateRepository extends JpaRepository<TbBamiTemplate, TbBamiTemplatePK> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM TB_BAMI_TEMPLATES WHERE referral_queue=:referralQueue AND TXN_TYPE=:txnType AND REFERRAL_RSN=:reffralRsn AND (:wlClause OR (ROLE='ALL' AND (TEMPLATE_TYPE='PUSH' OR TEMPLATE_TYPE='MAIL') )) AND ACTION=:action",nativeQuery=true)
    List<TbBamiTemplate> findRecordTemplateDetails(@Param("referralQueue")String referralQueue, @Param("txnType")String txnType,@Param("reffralRsn")String reffralRsn,@Param("action")String action,@Param("wlClause")String wlClause);
}
//wlClause is :(ROLE = OPS AND TEMPLATE_TYPE =MAIL) OR (ROLE = RM1 AND TEMPLATE_TYPE =PUSH) OR (ROLE = RM AND TEMPLATE_TYPE =PUSH) OR (ROLE = ARM AND TEMPLATE_TYPE =PUSH)
```

I am getting below exception:

```
  org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
  ....
  ....

 Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00920: invalid relational operator
```

Comment: `:wlClause OR` is wrong. What is the boolean value of a String?

Comment: :wlClause is a string which i am getting from other class.(ROLE = OPS AND TEMPLATE_TYPE =MAIL) OR (ROLE = RM1 AND TEMPLATE_TYPE =PUSH) OR (ROLE = RM AND TEMPLATE_TYPE =PUSH) OR (ROLE = ARM AND TEMPLATE_TYPE =PUSH)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the link [dba-oracle.com](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_00920_invalid_relational_operator.htm) :

> ORA-00920 invalid relational operator
> **Cause: A search condition was entered with an invalid or missing relational operator.**
>
> **Action:** Include a valid relational operator such as =, !=, ^=, <>, >,
> <, >=, <=, ALL, ANY, [NOT] BETWEEN, EXISTS, [NOT] IN, IS [NOT] NULL,
> or [NOT] LIKE in the condition.
>  If a search condition is entered
> along with a missing or invalid operator, ORA-00920 will be thrown.
> ORA-00920 can also be thrown if an executed SQL statement has a WHERE
> clause with an invalid relational operator.
>
> To correct ORA-00902, use a valid relational operator like:
>
> ```
> =   !=    ^=  <>  >
> < >=  <=  ALL ANY
> [NOT] BETWEEN EXISTS  [NOT] IN    IS[NOT] NULL    [NOT] LIKE
> ```

If you check closely you have an error in your query syntax :

```
SELECT
   * 
FROM
   TB_BAMI_TEMPLATES 
WHERE
   referral_queue = :referralQueue 
   AND TXN_TYPE = :txnType 
   AND REFERRAL_RSN = :reffralRsn 
   AND 
   (
      :wlClause //what is this mean, i think something wrong is here ?

      OR 
      (
         ROLE = 'ALL' 
         AND 
         (
            TEMPLATE_TYPE = 'PUSH' 
            OR TEMPLATE_TYPE = 'MAIL'
         )
      )
   )
   AND ACTION = :action
```

It should be :

```
...

something = :wlClause 

OR 

...
```

---

**EDIT**

### You can't pass a piece of query like a String!!

```
  ROLE = 'OPS' 
  AND TEMPLATE_TYPE = 'MAIL') 
  OR 
  (
     ROLE = 'RM1' 
     AND TEMPLATE_TYPE = 'PUSH'
  )
  OR 
  (
     ROLE = 'RM' 
     AND TEMPLATE_TYPE = 'PUSH'
  )
  OR 
  (
     ROLE = 'ARM' 
     AND TEMPLATE_TYPE = 'PUSH'
  )
```

Because when you try to do that, this will be set between two "query" and not like you imagine, so avoid this problem, i suggest to make a `NativeQuery` instead, and build your query with `StringBuilder` for example :

```
String[] roles = {"OPS", "RM1", "RM", "ARM"};//list of roles
String[] template_type = {"MAIL", "PUSH", "PUSH", "PUSH"};//list of template_type

StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
query.append("SELECT * FROM TB_BAMI_TEMPLATES WHERE referral_queue = :referralQueue AND TXN_TYPE = :txnType "
        + "AND REFERRAL_RSN = :reffralRsn AND (");

String del = "";
for (int i = 0; i < roles.length; i++) {
    query.append("(ROLE = '").append(roles[i]).append("' AND TEMPLATE_TYPE = '").append(template_type[i]).append("')");
    del = "OR";
    query.append(del);
}
query.append("(ROLE = 'ALL' AND (TEMPLATE_TYPE = 'PUSH' OR TEMPLATE_TYPE = 'MAIL')))AND ACTION = :action");

System.out.println(query.toString());

//Create your query, and set parameters then get your results
Query q = em.createNativeQuery(query.toString());
q.setParametter("referralQueue", referralQueue);
q.setParametter("txnType", txnType);
q.setParametter("reffralRsn", reffralRsn);
q.setParametter("action", action);

List<Type> = q.getResulList();
```

Comment: I have mentioned in my code(Repository class with comments) what is 'wlClause' ,Its a string I am passing,

Comment: it should be compared with a column name `colname = :wlClause` and not alone like you do, is that query run in your DBMS @user7352962 ?

Comment: @user7352962 can you show me your query that you make in your DBMS please ?

Comment: SELECT * FROM TB_BAMI_TEMPLATES WHERE referral_queue='FTC_DOC_RM' AND TXN_TYPE='NEW LC' AND REFERRAL_RSN='LIMIT EXPIRY' AND ((ROLE = 'OPS' AND TEMPLATE_TYPE ='MAIL') OR (ROLE = 'RM1' AND TEMPLATE_TYPE ='PUSH') OR (ROLE = 'RM' AND TEMPLATE_TYPE ='PUSH') OR (ROLE ='ARM' AND TEMPLATE_TYPE='PUSH') OR (ROLE='ALL' AND (TEMPLATE_TYPE='PUSH' OR TEMPLATE_TYPE='MAIL') )) AND ACTION='PENDING'

Comment: check my edit @user7352962 i think you misunderstood something in your query hope this can gives you an idea

Comment: Any references How to build query using  StringBuilder

Comment: mmm ok i will make a short example hope it could help you @user7352962 just a moment

Comment: Any links?? @YCF_L

Comment: ah you want links you can check this http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/1037/stringbuilder#t=201704080911042191302